# filtering by category in excel

Tags: excel, filtering

Working on an excel problem that probably has a simple solution. The sheet I am working with has a lot of excess data so I've boiled it down to a quick example.

Column B has categories, say cupcake flavors such as chocolate, vanilla, strawberry, etc. while columns D through O are labelled with dates, and each cell shows the quantity delivered for that date.

Simple example:
[image: Simple Example]

I would like to make a stacked column showing what portion of each day's total deliveries are each flavor, so I need to be able to count total number of each flavor on each day.

I can't think of a way to do this other than making a separate spreadsheet, and building a flavor specific corresponding table using if statements. For example =IF('DeliverySheet'!B4="Vanilla", 'DeliverySheet'!D4, 0) where 'DeliverySheet'!D4 would be the number of vanillas delivered for that order on that day. This would require a spreadsheet for each flavor, and typing out each condition for each cell. Is there a cleaner way to do filter by category?

My attempt:
[image: My attempt]

Comment: You could easily use `SUMIFS` to calculate the total for each flavor.

Comment: @BigBen, this definitely helps! But it still leaves a copy/paste issue. I can't copy or corner drag the cell since it will change both ranges. For example, =SUMIF(B5:B11, "Chocolate",I5:I11) copied one cell over will become =SUMIF(C5:C11, "Chocolate",J5:J11) when it should be =SUMIF(B5:B11, "Chocolate",J5:J11). This means I have to individually correct each cell and with let's say, 200 dates and 3 flavors, that's 600 cells. Any thoughts?

Comment: `=SUMIFS($B5:$B11,"Chocolate",I5:I11)`.

Comment: @BigBen that totally works and is sooo satisfying. Thank you!